# raise_error and raise_exception are not working for me in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
describe "The Original Method list_instances_of_with_resources_change" do  
    it  "Should execute successfully and return Array of Google::Apis::DnsV1::Change object" do  
    expect{subject_class::list_instances_of_with_resources_change("Dummy ID",custom_params)}.to raise_error       
   end  
end
```

The error which I am getting.

```
2) Testing Change Resource :  The Original Method list_instances_of_with_resources_change Should execute successfully and return Array of Google::Apis::DnsV1::Change object
     Failure/Error: response = client.send("list_changes", project, managed_zone, max_results:max_results, page_token:page_token, sort_by:sort_by, sort_order:sort_order)

     Google::Apis::ClientError:
       invalid: Invalid value for project: graphite-development1
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.4/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:211:in `check_status'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.4/lib/google/apis/core/api_command.rb:102:in `check_status'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.4/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:179:in `process_response'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.4/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:286:in `execute_once'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.4/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:107:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:54:in `block in retriable'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `times'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `retriable'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.4/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:104:in `block in execute'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:54:in `block in retriable'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `times'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `retriable'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.4/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:96:in `execute'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.4/lib/google/apis/core/base_service.rb:345:in `execute_or_queue_command'
     # /home/vivekkumarmishra17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.4/generated/google/apis/dns_v1/service.rb:191:in `list_changes'
     # ./lib/puppet_x/puppetlabs/google_cloud_dns/provider.rb:165:in `list_instances_of_change'
     # ./spec/unit/neg_google_cloud_dns_change_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: your test description ('should execute successfully') does not match the test itself (should throw an error). if you write sloppily, you can expect sloppy behaviour.

Comment: Ok. However the description text is no where responsible for this fialure. I have changed that with my original code, but it's still failing.

Comment: Is the spec in line 24? What is `subject_class`? How is `list_instances_of_with_resources_change` implemented?

Comment: subject_class is an object of class, which is having list_instances_of_with_resources_change as it's method. However I solved the problem. Actually when i am declaring anything wrong in global variable which is to be passed in the list_instances_of_with_resources_change method, it's failing. However if I am giving it correct in global variable and again declaring those variable wrong in local in the the above code, it's passing.